# What is a commonly used term for "Arranged for piano and voice" in regards to popular music recordings?

Tags: piano, terminology, accompaniment

Generally, searching for "piano cover" + a popular song's name in DDG, Google, and YouTube yields videos of instrumental covers, not someone's personal accompanying-instrument-and-voice arrangement that they play for the video, as one would find searching "guitar cover." If one wants to listen to instrumental guitar covers, one can use "instrumental guitar cover" or, even better, "fingerstyle cover" [guitar is implicit; most results aren't ukulele]. **What is a search term most likely to yield recordings of piano and voice arrangements of other popular songs?**

**EDIT**:

Original title: What is a commonly used term for "Arranged for piano and voice"?

To clarify: I am looking for recordings, as video or audio files, and not sheet music. Except for tutorial videos for beginners, these mostly tend to be instrumental arrangements.

Comment: As a tangent, "banjo cover" is a hit-or-miss as to whether the result is arpeggios + singing or fingerstyle instrumental.

Answer (score 1):

Piano/Vocal.   Maybe Piano/Vocal/Guitar (doubtless chord symbols, maybe chord shapes too will be included). Sometimes abbreviated to 'PV' or 'PVG'.

But you don't need to search for any of these.  Just search the song title.   Piano and voice is the default arrangement.

'Cover' is a term far more commonly attached to a recording than to a printed arrangement.  Unless, of course, you're referring to a pictorial cover page.

Answer (score 0):

Like Laurence says: searching for the title is sufficient!

Google chrome shows you automatically the option **Piano** (sheet and videos) and if you look up title and the choose pictures you have a big selection of sheet music.

And yes, the term is piano/vocal if you are looking e.g. in a shop for a book. There are rarely piano editions without  lyrics in a separate vocal systems. Usually the guitar chords are added.